# Does heavy armour penalize sneaking when I cast Muffle?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, does heavy armour still penalize Sneak when Muffle is cast, or when wearing boots with the Muffle property?

Comment: Related: [Muffle Magnitude Difference](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50130/4797)

Answer (score 5):

According to this [answer from the 'Muffle Magnitude Difference' question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50154/4797), casting the Muffle spell gives 100% armor noise reduction. If you're sneaking, it won't matter if you're using Heavy or Light armor with the Muffle spell.

As to boots with the Muffle spell enchantment, the [Nightingale Boots (level 1-18 version)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Boots#Nightingale_Boots) gets 25% noise reduction, while the [Nightingale Boots (level 32+ version)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Boots#Nightingale_Boots)  and [Predator's Grace](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Predator%27s_Grace#Predator.27s_Grace) provides 100% noise reduction. Everything else gets 50% noise reduction. If you are using boots with < 100% noise reduction, [Heavy Armor will still penalize sneaking](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heavy_Armor#Comparison_to_Light_Armor).

Also [(from this answer)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50154/4797):

> Apparently, any item enchanted by the player with the Muffle effect will have 1.0 [100% armor noise reduction]. This number is not affected by your enchanting level or gem size used on the enchanting process.

Answer (score 1):

"It is unclear whether or not the magnitude of the Muffle effect is significant. Based on the description of the Muffled Movement perk (Noise from armor is reduced 50%), a magnitude of 0.5 is equivalent to a 50% reduction. However, the magnitude of enchantments and spells is never displayed in-game, suggesting that the magnitude does not matter. If the magnitude is significant, most enchanted items have a magnitude of 0.5, implying they are only 50% effective"

According to this from the UESP, yes Heavy Armour does still penalize sneak when muffle is cast. Muffle only reduces detection by 50%