# Can you really hear the noise made by heavy armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found the next questions:
*[Muffle magnitude difference](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/is-there-any-way-to-fully-silence-my-heavy-armor)

[Is there any way to fully silence my heavy armor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/is-there-any-way-to-fully-silence-my-heavy-armor)

[Does heavy armour penalize sneaking when i cast muffle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38756/does-heavy-armour-penalize-sneaking-when-i-cast-muffle/72078#72078)*

But none of them talks about the actual noise. Can you really hear it? Maybe i'm deaf but i haven't heard any noise when i use heavy armor. (Playing on XBox, hometheater LG 5.1 (normal volume: 8) and a 3D screen LG 50")

Comment: its not so much that YOU hear it. it's the enemy AI. If you sneak while wearing heavy armor, you will be detected at a much shorter distance than if you wear cloth. how much the distance difference is. I don't know.

Comment: @JLaBella Wouldn't it be you are detected at a _longer_ distance? The way you have it worded sounds like you need to be closer in heavy armor to be detected. Which is, obviously, the opposite.

Comment: @JLaBella Would sure have been nice if you posted that as an answer.

Comment: @LpSamuelm I didn't have it has an answer because I don't have any hard facts to back it. just speculation.

Comment: @JLaBella Ah, okay. It seemed like you knew.

Comment: @JLaBella I wouldn't call that *speculation*. That's just basic "how stealth works".

Comment: @SevenSidedDie true, That is how the stealth system works in skyrim, but what I don't know/have is the numbers for when you can be detected. If you think that is enough for an answer I will make it so.

Comment: @JLaBella Yeah, I'd think that's enough. The actual numbers aren't part of the question's problem, it's the core concept that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stealth system in Skyrim doesn't matter much about what *you* hear, but what the *AI* hears. When you are in heavy armor you are much louder and AI detects you at a longer distance than if you were in just cloth.

Muffle decreases this detection distance as the other questions you linked explain.